# Quaternion interpolation with SQUAD: Tangent issue

Tags: interpolation, quaternions, tangent-spaces

For interpolating between keyframes in an animation path I make use of `SQUAD(q1,q1_t,q2_t,q2)` function.
q1 and q2 beeing the points to interpolate and q1_t and q2_t the tangents in the points respectively.

A,B,C beeing rotations, and rotation direction beeing A -> B -> C then the tangent for B can be calculated
using

$$tang_n = q_n * exp(-\frac{log(q_n^{-1} * q_{n-1}) + log(q_n^{-1} * q_{n+1}) }{4})$$

with A = $q_{n-1}$, B = $q_n$, C = $q_{n+1}$

[Tangent formula page 98](https://books.google.de/books?id=h0NZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=quaternions%20squad%20issues&source=bl&ots=4lkZUbw8Qg&sig=ACfU3U0xUZFssRLWtpzYv9c83RehKvtHpA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWtP_BlfXpAhWKyqYKHa0cBzAQ6AEwAXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=quaternion%20inverse&f=false)

Animation path with interpolation looks like this:
[image]
with the problematic section marked in red.

Visualizing the rotations anywhere in the proper part of the path
with A = red, B = green, C = blue and B-tangent = yellow:
[image]
you can see that the tangent from B is close to the other rotations.

though in the bad part of the path, the visualization looks like this: 
[image]

The tangent in that section is totally off and thus the interpolation using SQUAD is not clean.

The formula for the tangent can be found in other documents as well, but none mentions any issue with the calculation.

[Video](https://youtu.be/o2CEZsLPv1Q)

I understand that quaternions are a 4th dimension representation of a rotation by using a rotation axis and an angle. I also understand how to compute the tangents in case of a location path. But the tangent calculation for quaternions is not something I understand and thus can't find the issue with it.

What is the problem with the formula that it works for the most part but has sometimes issues?

Comment: Could you please make your question clear?  Is this a mathematical theory question or a question about software?  Depending on what you want to know, this question may or may not be on-topic for this site.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't see where the question is not clear. Computation of tangents for quaternions given a publicated formula might result in tangents that causes issues in interpolation. 
Though you might be right about the wrong forum if you define math as: why is 1+1=2

Comment: What is not clear is that there isn't a question in your post at all.  You have implied questions, but it's unclear to me which implied question you are asking.  For example, are you asking about the formula and why it gives an unexpected answer (so the visualizations illustrate this behavior)?  Are you asking why the Unreal Engine exhibits bad behavior (perhaps due to round-off error or some other issue)?

Comment: I have added a specific question for you at the end of the post.

Comment: I also removed "Unreal Engine" as it is basically not necessary to mention it.

Comment: Though it might be an issue with one of Unreal Engines quaternion functions. I'm further investigating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, it is not an issue with the tangent function, but the function FQuat::Exp and/or FQuat::Log of Unreal Engine that was used to visualize the result.
By using functions Log/Exp defined according to [Link](https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/pub/quat.pdf) the problem was solved.